# Random Number Error in Test in Flutter Code

Tags: flutter

I have been working on a Flutter app that was put through a security check. The check revealed an issue with an insecure random number. After doing a thorough check, I have found no instances of random numbers or class `Random` used in my project.

The error reads:

```
Insecure Random Number Generator used, do not make use of java.lang.Random class.
```

If anyone can help us resolve this issue, please comment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the code needs to be cryptographically secure either if you have not used the RNG in your code. That logic isn't doing something like creating initialization vectors for a block cipher etc. so it ought to be fine...

This should not be an infosec issue as it is an auto-import, though it is not getting used anywhere in the primary code, sometimes we get this type of issue while developing cross-platform applications.

Below is an example where you have to make sure while implementing the RNG:

REF 1.

Secure Implementation — java.security.SecureRandom
A secure Random number generator is one that exhibits the following properties:-
It appears random
Its value is unpredictable
It cannot be reliably produced after generation
Java’s SecureRandom class provides the above-mentioned properties. The secure random class uses entropy to generate random numbers. Entropy is using unpredictable input as a source. It could be either using hardware or OS implementation or using system processes such as timing events or interrupts. The following is the block diagram implementation for the same.

REF 2.

http://www.thesis.bilkent.edu.tr/0006566.pdf